# Get amount from a string

Tags: php, regex

i am using php and i have a string like:-

```
$string ="i have 300 $, 1000$ ,500 euro in my account";
```

and I want to get the `300 $, 1000$ ,500 euro` and display.

and further remove the currencies and have only the amount and display.
Here is my code.

```
$allwords = preg_split("/\s+/", $string);
           $prices = array();
           foreach ($allwords as $word_value) {
               if (strpos($word_value, '$') !== false) {
                   $prices[] = str_replace(array(","), "", $word_value);
               }
           }
```

so far i am only able to get `1000$` from the string. please any help with be appreciated.

Comment: If you only want to get the numbers then you could use /\d{1,}/g

Comment: What about `1000  ¥` or `2000 yen` or other currencies? Do you also need to match those? Or just these 3 cases?

Comment: yea @WiktorStribiżew i would like to match those too

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew See my answer, implemented your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex [does what you're looking for](https://regex101.com/r/nQ6oJ1/1):

```
\d+(?:\s?(?:\$|euro))
```

In `PHP` code, this would be:

```
$string ="i have 300 $, 1000$ ,500 euro in my account";
$regex = '~\d+(?:\s?(?:\$|euro))~';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/BCha1a).
To actually get the digits (300,1000,500 in your case), you could use a capturing group like so:

```
$regex = '~(\d+)(?:\s?(?:\$|euro))~';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

To match other currencies as well (as @Wiktor pointed out), add these to the non-capturing group:

```
(\d+)(?:\s?(?:\$|euro|¥|yen))
```

To allow **float** values, change the pattern as follows:

```
([\d.]+)(?:\s?(?:\$|euro|¥|yen))
```

Comment: Or you could use something like `'/([\d]+)/'`.

Comment: @Max: Of course, the pattern could be simplified, but your's would match the age, a telephone number and the weight as well :) Using regular expressions is always a tradeoff between what to match and what to exclude. Additionally, in your case, the square brackets are not needed at all (`/(\d+)/` is the same).

Comment: True, but as I saw no other numbers besides money I assumed there would be no other numbers in the given string :)

Comment: thanks very much guys i appreciate ur help. Sorry if i didn't mention this initially by in that string i have phone numbers and  measurements(m/s,kg)

Comment: my string include values like ,
$string  = "20000.00$ sakwe 100.00 $ hello dollar 350yen 10 euro 256$";

Answer (score 0):

Simple & concise code can be

```
$prices = explode(',', $string);
foreach ($prices as $key => $value)   {         
$prices[$key] = floatval($value);
}
```